# Capture signature on screen

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way I can use Docusign API to only capture signature from my application and not sign a particular document?

I am trying embedded signing but it requires atleast one document to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your use case, but I would consider using DocuSign Click for this scenario where you need someone to sign but there's no document.
Read more about it:
https://www.docusign.com/products/click
and here for the APIs:
https://developers.docusign.com/click-api